# Blocked a frame with origin

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, webview, wkwebview

I am trying to load javascript to a webview to change color of frame. I am getting **"Blocked a frame with origin"** error while javascript is being applied.

> URL :
> https://checkout-testing.herokuapp.com/v3/hosted/pay/7f4d4fd48adde85420e3

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        let changeHtmlbuttonScript = """
        document.getElementById(checkout).style.backgroundColor = "#0331FC"
        """
        webView.evaluateJavaScript(changeHtmlbuttonScript) { (success, error) in
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

I have tried setting "Arbitrary loads" property to false but no success. Does anyone know how to solve this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame)

Comment: All that discussion is related to iframe not webview. I am not so sure if it all goes for webview as well.

Comment: well, there's no element with `id="checkout"`, but there's an element with `name="checkout"`, and it's an iframe. So yes, I think, this is the same problem - cross-origin feature.